# Проблема импорта стандартной библиотеки в python

Tags: python, virtualenv, библиотеки

При попытке приобщиться к стандартной библиотеке для программирования GUI Tkinter возникли неожиданные сложности:

```
In [2]: import Tkinter
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a0c812564da3> in <module>()
----> 1 import Tkinter

/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py in <module>()
     40     import _tkinter
     41 except ImportError, msg:
---> 42     raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
     43 tkinter = _tkinter # b/w compat for export
     44 TclError = _tkinter.TclError

ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

Система: Ubuntu 12.04LTS, python 2.7.3, запущенный в виртуальном окружении.

Comment: sudo aptitude install python-tk

Comment: Что интересно, в данном случае интерпретатор ищет библиотеку не в виртуальном окружении, а в "основном" каталоге, где установлен питон...

Comment: А может pip install python-tk?
Честно говоря, с виртуальным окружением не работал.

Comment: пробовал через pip, не помогало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tk` - стандартная либа, так что в виртуальное окружение её не нужно устанавливать дополнительно. Чтобы `tk` работал, питон должен быть собран с определенными настройками.

В убунте вместо пересборки можно установить пакет `python-tk/python3-tk`

Comment: В виртуальном окружении она была, а вот в реальном не было. Почему при активном виртуальном окружении интерпретатор пытался импортировать либу из глобального для меня не ясно. Видимо, надо переходить на buildout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python